# Spring-cloud-data-flow: how to paste default execution properties on each task execution

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I launched spring cloud data flow locally running tow jars: **spring-cloud-skipper-server-2.11.1.jar** and **spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.11.1.jar**

Now I want to add java-opts field but not manually each time I created or launching task. I wanted it was by default. I mean if I launching task I do not need to specify additional options.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaKKe.png)

I tried different option on server startup but it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the deployment properties on the task definition but you can set them as platform properties per environment. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-tasks) for details but **TL;DR** is if you add something like this to your app config:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      task:
        platform:
          local:
            accounts:
              default:
                javaOpts: "--add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"
```

You will see this when you launch your tasks:

```
2023-11-02 18:59:54.065  INFO 36609 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher      : Command to be executed: /Users/cbono/.sdkman/candidates/java/19.0.2-amzn/bin/java --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED -jar /Users/cbono/.m2/repository/io/spring/timestamp-task/2.0.2/timestamp-task-2.0.2.jar --app.timestamp.spring.cloud.task.initialize-enabled=false --app.timestamp.spring.batch.jdbc.table-prefix=BATCH_ --app.timestamp.spring.cloud.task.tablePrefix=TASK_ --app.timestamp.spring.cloud.task.schemaTarget=boot2 --app.timestamp.spring.cloud.deployer.bootVersion=2 --spring.cloud.task.executionid=1
2023-11-02 18:59:54.080  INFO 36609 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher      : launching task dd-09781bd9-285d-45d2-855b-5eb0b7480921
```